# Div positioning issue bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am facing problems on this div alignment and positioning. I am using bootstrap 3 where `col-md-12` is my parent div, `col-md-9` and `col-md-3` are my child div(s). This is a sample image of my design that I am facing problems with.

[image]

And can we make it responsive?

Here's my code so far: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2y5ntfg/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=z2y5ntfg)
(Please expand the view area to see the issue)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what problem are you having?

Comment: the div1 content is not sticking to div1 header. Please check the fiddle once.

Comment: Not sure I get that but either way, to make it responsive you need to define column widths for smaller devices too. Like "col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-9", for example.

Comment: You are adding: `style="padding-top: 15px"` to your col-md-3 divs and `padding-bottom: 15px` to your "header" div.  If you want both divs to "stick" together you will want to remove the padding.

Comment: @john_h that padding is for `web-icon` div. The grey color background is the content div which should be sticking to the header.

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest `.col` directly inside `.col`. You need to add `.row` as a wrapper for every `.col` level. See: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

After you do this your issues should be resolved.